# Blocking 3G connectivity for Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have successfully blocked 3G connectivity for my application for Android, as I just have to make some changes in the manifest file. 
Now I have the block the 3G connectivity for my App for Iphone. Can you please suggest me some easy way of blocking 3G connectivity for Iphone App...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the following settings to your info.plist as boolean value.

- UIRequiresPersistentWiFi - Ensures the device is connected via WiFi

If your choice is not true then the user will be presented with an appropriate message when starting your application. Best of all this message is from the OS and thus is localized.

Comment: I am using this [Reachability.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)  it is working quite fine!!!